# How to update field without JavaScript or without any JavaScript form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

C# WPF has the ability to update data with binding, but how to achieve such a thing in ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core without using any type of JavaScript?

Very simple example needed; I type text in input field and the text near it updates, I tested already DotVVM, but it still uses a modified form of JavaScript.

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve without JavaScript

```
<input type="text" id="here" onchange="medthod(this);"/>
<input type="text" id="output"/>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function medthod(input)
{
    document.getElementById("output").value = document.getElementById("here").value;
}
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls9czjw1/2/)

Comment: You need JavaScript. This is a page executed in the client browser. You can do a form submission, but that reloads and replaces the current page.

Comment: For defualt asp.net-core, it does not support two way model binding in the view. You may try client framework like angular or vue to implmenet two way binding wihtout manually writing this js. But, for depth implement for these libraries, they are also used js. In other words, it's impossible without js.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Comment: WPF as a desktop application has just a single environment. A web application has (at least) two: the browser (where the user can see it) and the server (that can access some data store). Data is *not* transferred automatically between the two, you have to explicitly code it.